How to print out CR and LF characters from .txt in C?
I have a .txt file containing 100 lines of code. After comparing the size of the file, provided by fseek() and ftell() functions, to the character count, I observed a 198 byte difference in file size - precisely 2x the number of lines (100 lines minus last line), indicating that Windows uses 2 characters to identify each line (confirmed by a trusty Wiki search).
I tried printing out the 2 characters at the end of the line using getc(), but was only able to print out the LF (ASCII code 10) char. The next character is simply the next character in file - no sign of RF anywhere.
Is it possible to access CR char and print it out in terminal?
Are .txt files "better" handled on Linux e.g. using only \n ([newline character] - just in case it gets lost in stack overflow formatting) to identify the end of the line?

In Windows, the size of a text file cannot be reliably known from fseek() and ftell(), because of the conversion of line end characters. Conversely, in Windows you should always open a binary file in "b" binary mode, to prevent the unwanted corruption of data through these conversions.

More information in this answer. What's "better"? Under Linux it seems that text files are always handled as binary. In my opinion files are always binary on modern devices. But if files are always treated as binary, then what use would "text mode" be? If you're wondering about the exact number of characters after binary encoding them then obviously binary mode should be considered rather than text mode.

"was only able to print out the LF (ASCII code 10) char". That's because the CRLF pair is filtered out to a single newline character. And when outputting in text mode, the newline is converted into two characters in the file.

After comparing the size of the file, provided by fseek() and ftell() functions Bad idea:  "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read."

And you can't safely fseek() to the end of a binary stream, either: "A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END." Also: "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream ..."

Closely related: Why Binary file is not a Text file and all Text files are Binary files?

@JohnBollinger Well, then there are these strange beasts: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=of-fopen-freopen-parameters  Good luck with fseek()/ftell() on some of those, even in "binary" format - the value ftell() returns is always "its file position indicator contains unspecified information"

You know you're in for a fun ride if you have to ask yourself if you have to open the file in "record" or "block" mode :P

@AndrewHenle Notice that it says stream, not file. In Windows and Unix  there's no problem using SEEK_END with real files, since files have known sizes.


Is it possible to access CR char and print it out in terminal?

C FILEs can be open in either text or binary mode.

In text mode, there may be bidirectional translation between the text conventions of the host environment and of the C internal model of a stream of characters with newlines (alone) as line separators.
This was more significant in the past, when there was a fairly wide variety of local conventions for text files.  These days, the primary difference among common host environments is line termination convention -- Windows uses CR/LF pairs, whereas most everybody else uses just LFs.

In binary mode, there is no translation, just a stream of raw bytes.
This is a distinction without much difference in most common operating environments, but on Windows, opening the file in binary mode would avoid CR/LF translation.


On Windows and Unix (including Linux and Mac), text vs. binary nature is a matter of interpretation of the file contents, not an inherent characteristic of the file. If you want to handle the two bytes of each CR/LF terminator explicitly, then that means you want to treat the file as binary.  That is specified when you open it:
    FILE *my_file = fopen("example.txt", "rb");

Note in particular the b in the open mode, "rb".  That's what specifies binary mode.  The default is text mode.
Having opened the file that way, you will be able to read the CR characters explicitly.  And if you open a file for writing in binary mode, then you'll need to write those CR characters explicitly too, if in fact you want them.
But an alternative answer is that generally, if you want to handle text files according to local convention, then you can ignore most of that.  Open text files in text mode.  Whatever the conventional line terminator is, will be presented to your program as a single LF.  And since the standard output is open in text mode by default, when you turn around and echo that LF to the standard output, it will be translated the other direction -- to CR/LF if that is the host environment's convention.

Are .txt files "better" handled on Linux e.g. using only \n ([newline character] - just in case it gets lost in stack overflow formatting) to identify the end of the line?

Files whose names end in .txt should be handled appropriately for their contents.  Anywhere.
If the extension can be taken to convey that the file conforms to the text conventions of the host environment -- whether Windows, Linux, or whatever -- then it should be read and written in text mode.  The same C source code will accomplish this on Linux as does so on Windows.  That code will recognize newlines (alone) as line terminators.
If the extension should be taken to mean a file that conforms to some specific text conventions, say Windows', then such files should be handled appropriately for those conventions.  That probably means accessing them in binary mode if you want the code to be portable.  Reading Windows text files on Linux and interpreting them as they would be interpreted on Windows involves manually filtering out the CR of each CR/LF pair.
Or were you asking for a comparison of Windows and Linux text conventions?
The use of CR/LF line terminators instead of a single-character terminator is a legacy feature of Windows, and I'd argue that it was a legacy feature of MS-DOS before that.  It comes to us from the days of line-printer terminals, where the CR and LF control characters elicited separate physical operations from some such terminals -- returning the print head to the first column, and advancing the paper to the next line, respectively.  They can still produce distinct operations on video terminals, subject to terminal configuration. But none of that was ever a particularly strong justification for incorporating a two-byte line terminator into the text file format.

"...none of that was ever ... justification for..." Having served in a UNIX environment back in the days of lineprinters (and "DECwriters"), having CR and LF as two separate characters enabled, for instance, nroff to spool text output to a text file that incorporated overstrike for highlighting. The file would then be copied "as is" to the hardcopy device at a convenient time. Even during the late '80s (MS-DOS), a range of compact dot-matrix printers occupied desktops in offices... What a buzz that was, when 6 were in use at the same time! Those were the days, my friend.

@Fe2O3, I wholly appreciate the control functions of CR and LF and other control characters.  This answer even describes them. My closing point is that the connection between those and local text file conventions is weak.  "Text file" never needed to mean "data pre-formatted for our local line printer".  That multiple conventions arose (not to mention more esoteric text formats) underscores that.

MS-DOS 1.0 was developed with $$$ from IBM... Pure speculation: Bill sought to keep his backers as happy as he could. Reasonable, then, to presume he'd use a file format that "fed into" Big Blue's notion of industrial (line printer) production (incl. storage of that stuff.) And, a star (a legacy) was born... Just my idle time thoughts on why things are the way they are today. Cheers! :-)

Footnote: Back in the day, generating a "report" could occupy a CPU for many (expensive!!) seconds, minutes or hours. Printing the report transports its info from "cyberspace" to the real world where the paper copy is subject to abuses (like someone's spilt coffee, or worse.) Being able to merely re-print from a stored "electronic copy" is nothing more than good planning... Again, I was nowhere near the offices when/where these decisions were made. Just speculating... (Oops! Was it "PC-DOS", not "MS-DOS"... "Dave... my mind is going... I can feel it, Dave..." :-)
